# confusing subject-verb agreement

Tags: verbs, articles

Good day,
Which of these two is correct?

> 1. What I hate most is how **the** cannons look

Or

> 2. What I hate most is how **the** cannons looks.

Given the article above, this question seems impossible to be explained in a grammar book, as it will not perfectly answer **infinitive form of the verb+article**, it's a 'juggle'.

I believe this advanced site will help me clarify this though.
I've done my research already. Pls help. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are multiple cannons, the first of your number 1s is correct. I believe the valid options are:
1. What I hate most is how the cannons look
2. What I hate most is how the cannon looks
This is subject/verb agreement.

Comment: Hello, Kekst. As Don Bron has said, 'Answering off-topic questions on the ... site sends the wrong message to the user-base.' And as Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.'